# margin-left and margin-right auto, can't centered

Tags: html, css

I am not able to center my `<div>` with this css in IE:

```
height: 842px;
width: 595px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

What could be the reason and how to solve it?

Comment: provide some code and some css.

Comment: improve your question.your question is not clear enough...
"i can't center my with this css in IE." center what?make a clear statement about your problem.

Comment: Please provide code. Can't center what? What sort of element is it?

Comment: The issue lies with the container(s) then.

Answer (score 6):

You are either using IE 5 (or older) or your page is triggering [Quirks Mode](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/) which will make Internet Explorer emulate various bugs in older versions of the browser (including not supporting auto margins on block elements, treating `width` as *element width* instead of *content width*, and treating a length of `12` as `12px`).

Add a standards mode triggering Doctype to the top of your document (and forget about ancient, unsupported versions of IE).

For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Comment: Thank you. In my case the DOCTYPE definition was <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"> and caused the problem in IE.

Answer (score 2):

with your css select your element and add this.

```
#element{
    height: 842px;
    width: 595px;
    margin: 0 auto; /* this allows for no margin on top or bottom and centers middle */
}
```

Comment: then like @alexander Stover said, the problem is with the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
html, body {
    margin  : 0;
    padding : 0;
    width   : 100%;
    height  : 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Text align center, this method works for internet explorer and requires you to put "text-align:center" css attribute in your "body" style and later reset it by adding "text-align:left" (or right) in your divs (or other layout structure). This method works on all versions of internet explorer.

```
body
{
    /*some browsers add margins and padding by default, remove them*/
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    /* center everything for ie*/
    text-align:center;
}
```

OR by a `div`

```
<div align="center">
This is some text!
</div>
```

Or by taking postion as `absolute`

```
<div style="position: absolute; left:300px; top: 400px;">
//adjust left and top pixels according to your suitability
</div>
```